# Deserialize a removed type to a new type (old base class) in DataContractSerializer

Tags: .net, vb.net, datacontractserializer

Here is my old class diagram (simplified).

```
public class Main
    Public Property ListOfA As ClassACollection
End Class

Public Class ClassBase
End Class

Public Class ClassA
  Inherits ClassBase
End Class

Public Class ClassACollection
    Inherits System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of ClassA)
End Class

Public Class ClassB
  Inherits ClassBase
End Class

Public Class ClassBCollection
    Inherits System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of ClassB)
End Class
```

When i serialized the class `Main` with `DataContractSerializer` i got a XML like this :

```
<Main>
  <ListOfA>
    <ClassA>
      .....
    </ClassA>
    <ClassA>
      .....
    </ClassA>
  </ListOfA>
</Main>
```

Lately i removed `ClassA` and `ClassB` cause they were identical! I removed both collections to replace them with this :

```
public class Main
    Public Property ListOfA As ClassBaseCollection
End Class

Public Class ClassBaseCollection
    Inherits System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of ClassBase)
End Class
```

But now when I try to deserialize the XML, the collection `ListOfA` is created but always empty! I got no error during the deserialization.

I tried to use a `DataContractResolver`, but the function `ResolveName` is never call for `ClassA` or `ClassB`.

```
Dim dc As New Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(GetType(Main), Nothing, Integer.MaxValue, False, True, Nothing, New MyResolver())

Private Class MyResolver
    Inherits Runtime.Serialization.DataContractResolver

    Public Overrides Function ResolveName(typeName As String, typeNamespace As String, declaredType As System.Type, knownTypeResolver As System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractResolver) As System.Type
      If typeName.Equals("ClassA") OrElse typeName.Equals("ClassB") Then
        Return GetType(ClassBase)
      Else
        'Defer to the known type resolver
        Return knownTypeResolver.ResolveName(typeName, typeNamespace, Nothing, Nothing)
      End If
  End Function
End Class
```

Is the `DataContractResolver` to good way to do what i want?
If yes, do i need something else to make the `DataContractResolver` work ?

Thanks for your help!

---

**Update :**
I added back `ClassA` and `ClassB` in my project to do the following tests :
 - I tried to put them as known data types in the `DataContractSerializer` constructor.
 - I tried the `KnownTypeAttribute` on the ClassBaseCollection`.

In this 2 situations, `ResolveName` is still not called for `ClassA` and `ClassB`.

I tried to use a class derived from `IDataContractSurrogate` and convert the type in the function `GetDataContractType` and this function isn't call for `ClassA` and `ClassB`.

---

**Update #2:**
Finally, i didn't find any way to do what i wanted. I needed to look at the file version and replace old tag by new tag in the XML before serialization. Ex. :

```
data = data.Replace("<ClassA>", "<ClassBase>")
...
```

It's not an answer to my first question, but a workaround.

Comment: The msdn page on [Data Contract Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731138.aspx) might be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

> But now when I try to deserialize the XML, the collection `ListOfA` is
>   created but always empty! I got no error during the deserialization.

In the [msdn documentation on Data Contract Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731138.aspx) you can find info on why `ListOfA` is empty. The deserialization engine of your adjusted version can't interpret `ClassA` or `ClassB` and thus discards this data.

I think you are on the right tracking using a [Data Contract Resolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358759.aspx).

> A data contract resolver allows you to configure known types
>   dynamically. **Known types are required when serializing or
>   deserializing a type not expected by a data contract**.

Since you didn't specify `ClassA` and `ClassB` in the known data types parameter of the [`DataContractSerializer` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd438223.aspx), `ResolveName()` is not called for them. For more information on Known Data Types, [check the msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx). This means in order to correctly deserialize these old classes, you will still need to include them for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I understand why my list is empty. Thanks. Yes i'm deserializing. ResolveName() is call for other types, but not for ClassA or ClassB. I edited my post to clarify this point.

Comment: @Kipotlov I'm afraid you will have to keep the `ClassA` and `ClassB` declaration around. See my updated answer.

Comment: I tried to put `ClassA` and `ClassB` as known data types in the `DataContractSerializer` constructor, i tried the `KnownTypeAttribute` on the `ClassBaseCollection` and `ResolveName` is still not called for `ClassA` and `ClassB`...

Comment: @Kipotlov Did you put them in the exact same namespace/assembly as previously? Try serializing them and see whether the newly introduced types compare to the data you are trying to deserialize. (e.g. open the serialized data in a text editor)

Comment: @Kipotlov In that case I'm afraid I ran out of ideas. :/ Be sure to answer your own question if you do find the solution!